# Remove indentation line in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: jupyter-lab

I have a good chunk of code which I have pasted in a JupyterLab notebook.

And while in VS-Code it looks fine, here it the indentation is marked with a grey lines:

[image]

How to remove them without going line by line?

Answer (score 8):

A quick hack: `select all` >> `Tab` >> `Ctrl+[`